# Chrome extension for incognito tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, incognito-mode

I am developing an extension that interacts with a website of ours.
The interaction is created by sending messages along and handling those.

Sometimes I want to open our website in incognito mode and there, the extension is not working. It looks to me that the `listeners` on `chrome.runtime.onMessage` are not triggered.

in my `contentScript.js` I have something like

```
window.addEventListener(
  'message',
  (event, r) => {
    //check for sender and type otherwise return;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data);
  }
);
```

The extension creates a `devtools_page`, which loads a `.html`.
On that page I have

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messageHandler)
```

the `messageHandler` is never triggered. I can even check if the listener is there with `chrome.runtime.onMessage.hasListener(messageHandler)`, which returns `true`.

Even when I put the listener in the `background.js` (set in the `manifest.json`), this listener is never triggered.

I tried to put `"incognito": "split"` into the `manifest.json` but then the browser crashed completely when I open the page in incognito tab. For permissions, I have `["cookies", "tabs"]`.

**Update:** I enabled the extension in incognito mode on the extensions settings page

**Update:** As I said, when setting `"incognito": "split"`, the browser crashes. I narrowed it down to my `contentScript.js` which is loaded by the manifest `"content_scripts"`. I removed everything. Loading the page, the browser does not crash. But as soon as I run `window.addEventListener`, the browser crashes when I open the site on an incognito tab

**Update:** in the `windowAddEventListener` I do a `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data)`. I do this to make the website able to send necessary information to the extension to show the data. When removing `chrome.runtime.sendMassage`, the browser does not crash in incognito mode with `"incognito":"split"`

Comment: Can you enable the extension for incognito mode in the settings?

Comment: I enabled the extension in incognito mode but the problem still exists

Answer (score 1):

Chrome blocks extensions in Incognito mode,

So to test it you can allow certain extensions to work on incognito mode,

1. Click the menu button in Chrome.
2. Navigate to More Tools > Extensions.
3. In the new tab that opens, scroll through the list to find the extension you want to enable while incognito.
4. Click the “Allow in Incognito” button.

Comment: Thanks. I did that already. Otherwise the tab in the dev-tools would not be available. So this is not the solution to my problem unfortunately.